# From Mongodb remote server can we download only the required collections to local machine

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Daily iam making the mongo dump to my local machine.But i just want only few collections to download is it possible to do that? 
And my command to download collection is as below.

mongodump -h $MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST -d countly -c fc3d4e90cfa6a1759ca8ca56021e7f18_rma -o /opt/app-root/src/hello -u 'admin' -p $MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD

I am trying to dump my collection to file called hello in the server and then download to local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mongo export](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to export a collection:

```
mongoexport -h <Remote_Host_address> -d <database_name> -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> -o <outputfile.json>
```

And use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to import the json file into your local db:

```
mongoimport -h <Local_Host_address> -d <database_name> -c <collection> --file outputfile.json
```

This implies that you can connect to the remote mongo database from your local machine. If not, you can export from the remote machine and then just `scp` to your box.

Note that it's **not recommended** to use mongoexport/import to do full backups of your db. Refer to the pages I linked for more information and parameters.